# Get product custom option value

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options

I have added a quantity field as per http://hkpatel201.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-add-custom-qty-to-custom-option.html

All is working well. Screenshot of the admin is http://snag.gy/H9zE4.jpg

I know the following code gets me the Option Type ID

```
$orderItemOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptions();                            
if (isset($orderItemOptions['options'][0]['option_value']))
{
    $selectedOrderItemOptionId = $orderItemOptions['options'][0]['option_value'];
}
```

But my question is how do I get the Option Type based on the ID?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach ($orderItem->getProductOptions() as $opt) {  
  $optionType = $opt->getType();  

  echo 'Type : '  . $optionType;
}
```

To load option by id

```
$id = 9;
$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($id); 
$opt->getType();
```

From your code above

```
$opt = $orderItemOptions['options'][0];
$optionType = $opt->getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
   $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
    foreach($productOptions['options'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value['label'];
    echo $value['option_value']
    }}?>
```